# Locate for Linux that includes filesize and permissions?

Tags: linux

Anyone know if there is a program for Linux that acts like locate / updatedb and family but includes file sizes and permissions?

I know find can do this, but I am looking for something that puts all this information in a db so the information could be looked up quickly.

The idea being, for example, that you could find out the size of directories (at the the time updatedb) etc very quickly if there was a system like this.  I don't want to just run stat or ls on locates output.

Comment: Are you averse to putting the filesizes into a DB?

Comment: Andy: Well, basically, that means doing this myself, or extended locate.  Which fine and I could do, I was just curious if something was out there already.

Comment: by the by, use `du` (I always use it with the `-xha` flags) to get directory size statistics

Answer (score 2):

You could always

```
ls -l `locate orderack`
```

Comment: Updated Question :-)

Comment: Updated answer :)

Comment: You make me sad. Like, really sad. "find / -name file.txt -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l" is marginly better, so you don't end up forking ls for every single file. Even better would be using "find / -name file.txt -printf '%y%M %u %g %s %p\n'". The formatting isn't exactly the same as ls -l, but it should be pretty close. This saves forks and stat syscalls.

Comment: and now you've changed your answer to make my comment look out of place. :(

Comment: Doesn't really matter, maybe I am not explaining this well, but I want the size of the files and the permissions to be in the DB. I doubt ls -l $(locate foo) would be much faster (if not slower) than the find command..

Comment: Review the edits and you'll see the answer was changed in relation to the question, not your comment

Comment: "ls -l $(locate foo)" will be as quick as you want, but isn't safe in the face of spaces.

Comment: It would not be as quick as what I want, updated my post again:-) Although this isn't what I want, a space friendly version would be: while read file; do stat -c "%n %s" "$file"; done < <(locate foo)

Comment: @Andy: The kind of result I would want comes from this variation: `ls -ld $(locate -b foo)`

Answer (score 0):

for file in $(locate BLAH); do ls -lah $file; done

I believe this prevents forking, but I can't be certain.it was quite fast for me.

Comment: You need to quote $file or spaces will break it.

Comment: Oh and you are still forking ls for every file.

Comment: "locate -0 foo | xargs -0 ls -l" should be both efficient and space-safe.

Answer (score 0):

It's not *exactly* what you're looking for, but this should work:

```
locate <pattern> | xargs ls -lh
```